# Timeout for opening a FIFO and also for writing/reading to/from a FIFO

Tags: c, fork, named-pipes

I want to achieve the communication between many clients (via many terminals). In my program I have forks so many children could do jobs simultaneously. My problem is that when a client (for example client 2) opens a named-pipe (for example with client 3) it opens the 2_to_3 named-pipe, and after that the client 2 waits for client 3 to also open the 2_to_3 named-pipe. I want to put a timer so my clients won't block (not at the opening and not at the writing/reading).

```
char *pipename=malloc(50*sizeof(char));
strcpy(pipename,"project/");
strcat(pipename,firstclient);
strcat(pipename,"_to_");
strcat(pipename,secondclient);
int ret_val=mkfifo(pipename,0666);
char *buf=malloc(100*sizeof(char));
//we fill the buf with something
int fd;
fd=open(pipename,O_WRONLY);

write(fd,buf,100);
```

Comment: If you use `malloc` with fixed compile-time literal constant sizes, why not use arrays instead?

Comment: You can mess around with `O_NONBLOCK` options to avoid all blocking.  Timeouts are harder; you'll need to use an appropriate notification mechanism, such as [`timer_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html)
and its family of related functions.

Comment: As for your problem, will opening a pipe *ever* block? Reading from/writing to the pipe may block (unless you make the descriptor non-blocking), but opening?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can you be a little more specific?I am new to all these system calls and their philosophy so sorry for my awareness.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: If you open a FIFO for reading, the call doesn't return until there's a process with the FIFO open for writing; conversely, if you open a FIFO for writing, the call doesn't return until there's a process with the FIFO open for reading.  That is, the first process to open a FIFO is blocked until there's a corresponding process also with the FIFO open for the opposite action.

Comment: I'm being lazy; I don't want to spend the time writing an answer, so I haven't written one (something to do with "bedtime").  I can point you to the specifications — that's why there's a link behind `timer_create()` in my previous comment.  You can look at [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html),
[`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html), and
[`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)
to find out more about the behaviour of `O_NONBLOCK`.

Comment: Okay i hope i will find the answer.Thanks for your time.